# How to remove reflected light from glass? [Blender 2.92]

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

As you can see, at the image above, I used 4 lights to illuminate my scene but their area light squares is showing up and I don't want it to show up. What can I do using Blender 2.92?

Comment: Try changing the light's "Size" property to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the direct light reflections by un-checking the *Glossy Ray* visibility in the *Object Properties* of the light (you will need to do this for each light you don't want reflected):

[image: Light]

Comment: Neat!   It appears that this checkbox only appears if Cycles is selected as the Render Engine, didn't know that there are sometimes properties that are tied to render engines!  If I choose Eevee I still see a reflection.  Any cure for Eevee?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't mention that. You tagged the question under "Cycles", so I didn't think it would be a problem. I'm not sure how it works in eevee, because light is approximated and "rays" don't really come into play as they do in Cycles. If anyone knows a solution for eevee, I would love to know what it is.

Comment: How are you makes those nice support gifs?

Comment: Simple, free program called "Screen to GIF".